# how to query in object stored in redis ? SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, redis

I am planning to use redis for the cache server. now I would like to query inside the object not only hash key data.

Suppose there is a Properties(id, application, environment, feature, key, value) collection. I stored Properties in redis against the key of id.

Now I need to query data where (application, environment, feature) condition.

Comment: Please be more specific about what exactly you need help with.

Comment: Select * from Properties 
where application = "jack" && environment = "dev"
i would like to get this kind of data using redis

Comment: In this case https://oss.redis.com/redisearch/ might be your best option.  Brewdis https://github.com/redis-developer/brewdis/blob/master/README.adoc is an example app using SpringBoot that might help you in that direction